# Como habilitar tooltip em inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte Tooltip:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Tooltips
 $(".tip_trigger").hover(function(){
  tip = $(this).find('.tip');
  tip.show(); //Show tooltip
 }, function() {
  tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip    
 }).mousemove(function(e) {
  var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
  var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
  var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
  var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip
  
  //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
  var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
  //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
  var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);
    
  if ( tipVisX < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
   mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
  } if ( tipVisY < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
   mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
  } 
  tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0; padding: 0;
 font: normal 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.8em;
 color: #333;
}
* {outline: none;}
img {border: none;}
h1 {
 font: 4em normal Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
 padding: 10px 0;
 color: #aaa;
 text-align: center;
}
h1 span { color: #666; }
h1 small{
 font: 0.3em normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.65em;
 display: block;
 color: #666;
}
h1 a {text-decoration: none;}
a {color: #d60000; text-decoration: none;}

/*--Tooltip Styles--*/
.tip {
 color: #fff;
 background:#1d1d1d;
 display:none; /*--Hides by default--*/
 padding:10px;
 position:absolute; z-index:1000;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.container {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a class="tip_trigger">
       sss     
        <span class="tip" style="top: 213px; left: 309px; display: none; ">sssssss</span> 
    </a>

<br><Br><br>
<input  type='text'  class="tip_trigger" id='inputNormal' name='nome'>
```

Como faço para ele funcionar no input?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
$('#mytext').popover();
$('#name').popover();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <label for="mytext">My Text:</label>
      <input id="mytext" class="form-control" type="text" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="My popover content." />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="My popover content.My popover content.My popover content.My popover content." />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A magica esta aqui:

```
data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Meu conteúdo"
```